# Как происходит процесс проверки приложения во время его публикации на play market

Tags: android, playmarket

Каким образом проверяются приложения при загрузке на play market. Смотрять ли приложение мануальные тестировшики? Что проверяется автоматическая проверка? Есть ли какие-либо зависимости, использование которых заведомо приведёт к реджекту? Может ли условный калькулятор с правами на осуществление звонков пройти проверку и быть выложенным в play market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достоверно ничего не известно. Однако, согласно наблюдениям можно сказать что

1. Во первых, после публикации, идёт автоматическая проверка. Проверяется много чего. Описание приложения, графика, возрастной рейтинг контент и прочая. Нейронная сеть тут может среагировать как угодно и забанить приложение даже без единого нарушения.
2. Иногда/всегда после публикации проверяет ещё и человек. Что он проверяет - неизвестно и не будет известно, чтобы недобросовестные разработчики не могли найти способ обойти проверку. Проверяет, вроде, аутсорс из Индии. Т.е. забанить могут за всё что угодно. Опять лотерея.
3. Периодически робот проверяет все приложения. Может проверить через час после одобрения приложения, а может через месяц/год. И может забанить приложение.

По идее условный калькулятор с правами на осуществление звонков проверку пройдёт. Но забанить могут в любой момент по любой причине и причину эту, обычно, не называют.

Немного историй по сему поводу можете в телеграмме почитать: https://t.me/android_developers_ban

Comment: А альтернативные PlayMarket-ы, куда можно выложить и скачать что угодно, без всяких проверок и обязательств существуют?

Comment: @avp, альтернативные существуют, я, например, в Amazon выкладываю. Есть и другие. Но вот чтобы без проверок и обязательств... Такого, думаю, нет. Если совсем надо - можно просто APK файл на сайт выложить и пусть юзер напрямую качает и на телефон ставит.

Comment: Понятно. Значит общеизвестный (легко доступный для скачивания всем) "черный рынок" отсутствует

Comment: @avp, он просто не может существовать. Гугл закручивает гайки - без разрешения на установку из неизвестных источников приложение не установить. Теперь, к тому же, это не разрешение на уровне ОС, но отдельное разрешение на каждое приложение-магазин (будь то браузер или Amazon). И даже при наличии разрешения установку будет блокировать либо баг ОС (на Xiomi и OnePlus требуется лезть в настройки разработчика и отключать специальную фичу чтобы приложение не из PlayMarket можно было установить) или гугл - без очень сильно запрятанной настройки магазины сторонние работать не будут.

Comment: @avp, вот тут есть инструкция со скринами как не из PlayMarket приложение установить. Там тот ещё адЪ, обычный юзер просто не разберётся. https://scpfoundation.app

Comment: А что делает это SCP?

Comment: @avp, это просто offline читалка для сайта, где тысячи нучно-фантастических и horror рассказов, создаваемых совместно международным комьюнити под свободной лицензией. Забанено в PlayMarket за нарушение авторских прав. И гуглу плевать на `Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License` которая всё это разрешает использовать.

Comment: Ох уж эти авторские права... Пора, что ли, уже объявлять гугл "империей зла"?

Comment: @avp, таки давно пора) Для меня, по крайней мере, это уже самоочевидный факт и я собираюсь потратить часть своего свободного времени на донесение этой информации до широкой общественности)

Comment: @avp империй добра не бывает. Особенно касается монополистов

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не согласен, что причину бана не называют. Называют а также присылают инструкцию как это следует устранить, за что Googl'у спасибо.

Comment: @Style-7, это скорее исключение, чем правило. Вы, наверное, имеете в виду удаление (не путать с баном) приложения по причине типа "Нет ссылки на политику конфиденциальности" или "Нет явного запроса юзеру на сбор его персональных данных". В этом случае да, приложение просто убрано с публикации, вы его обновляете и всё ОК. Я же говорю про случаи полного бана приложения. Например случаи, когда приложение банят за обнажёнку, люди пытаются выяснить что именно гуглу не понравилось, с большим трудом выясняют, но приложение так и не восстанавливают.

Comment: хотя такая же картинка есть в других приложениях, но их не банят (наверное потому, что это facebook или twitch). Т.е. им не дают возможности удалить картинку и вернуть приложение. Ссылку найти не смог, там было приложение - соц.сеть для художников и у них были модераторы, которые контент чистили. Однако приложение со всеми отзывами и установками они навсегда потеряли.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Ну да, я имел ввиду удаление.